# problem with adding mysql db in visual studio data sources

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, rider, .net-4.8

I'm using following program versions:

- Visual Studio 2019 16.11.19
- MySql 8.0.30
- NET connector 8.0.30
- MySQL for visual 1.2.10

When trying to add my database I get this error in VS

[image]

In Rider I can connect my database but then when I try to use DataGridView in .NET Framework (4.8) project - it doesn't show this database.

[image]

Comment: Can you please translate the error message in your first image to English?

Comment: I changed the first image, now it's in english

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html#connector-net-ef6-requirements

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: You could refer to [To bind the control to a data source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/bind-data-to-the-datagrid-using-the-designer?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#to-bind-the-control-to-a-data-source) and [Data Source Configuration Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/w4dd7z6t(v=vs.120)). That could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the issue, I had to install "Data storage and processing" in visual studio installer, now it works. :)